# UIPrintInteractionController Display Printer Connecting Status

Tags: objective-c, printing, airprint

I've been using the UIPrintInteractionController with a preselected UIPrinter to allow users of our app to print without presenting the dialog to select a device. One problem we're having, however, is that even though the controller knows which printer to send the job to, it still presents a screen stating that the device is "Contacting Printer..." and "Preparing..." with a "Cancel" button just below. This is causing a problem in that users of the kiosk are canceling the job without realizing that it interrupts the label generation process.

Is there a way to eliminate this dialogue? Make it so that the controller handles the printer interaction in the background?

Here's my code for sending the job:

```
NSURL* url         = [NSURL URLWithString:printerId];
UIPrinter* printer = [UIPrinter printerWithURL:url];

[controller printToPrinter:printer completionHandler:
 ^(UIPrintInteractionController *ctrl, BOOL ok, NSError *e) {
     CDVPluginResult* pluginResult =
     [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                         messageAsBool:ok];

     [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult
                                 callbackId:_callbackId];
 }];
```

Thanks for the help!

[image: UIPrintInteractionController displays a Contacting Printer message]

Comment: did u find out solution?

Comment: can u post your full code, without showing dialog box how to print?